# In Nginx is there a way to log 301 redirects?

Tags: nginx

In Nginx is there a way to log 301 redirects? I've tried enabling the logging at info level but they don't seem to be showing.

Comment: All responses from the server should appear in the access log, including 301 responses.

Comment: Thanks Richard - yes I was looking in the wrong log entirely!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

301 redirects are logged by default in Nginx. Here's an example from one of my log files

```
x.x.x.x [04/Jun/2017:03:43:08 +1200] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)" www.example.com 0.000 - https
```

Nginx access and error logs don't have levels like "info" as you said in your questions, at least as far as I'm aware. PHP does.

If your Nginx instance isn't logging 301 redirects you'll need to edit your question to include the nginx.conf and the server block that's not logging. You should also include a curl to a URL that should redirect, and the matching access logs.

Comment: Found it, thanks Tim. I was looking in the error_log and hadn't even considered there being another type of log file. Btw it seems the error_log can be set to eight different levels but as you say, not for the access_log.